# if statement in oracle package

Tags: oracle, if-statement

i have different products that uses the following  spec table

```
 ID NO  desccription       MIN      MAX      L       U  
 1  1    p                 0.0       7.5    5.5     8.0 
 2  2    s                 0.0       0.0    93.0    0.0 
 3  3    i                 0.0       2.0    0.0     4.0
```

when a new product comes in it compares its self to this table for example if i have the following product details

```
product 1001 i must be less than 2%
         s must be 93% or greater
         p must be between 5.5 and 7.5
```

It will take this details compare it to the spec table and get all necessary details related to product 1001 as ff:

```
if p >= L and p<= p_max and s >= s_L  then
if i >= i_min and i <= i_max then
Select statement goes here
```

this works fine for product 1001.

```
But now i have a product 1002 with i must be less than equal to 1%
                               s must be 93% or greater
                               p must be between 6.0 and 8.0
```

i tried the following

```
if  p > l and p < p_max  and s >= s_l then
if i < i_max and i = i_min
```

however this is not getting me the product 1002 it still gets me the product 1001.since both products are similar i am not sure how to go about it

Comment: sorry but your question is not clear p_max  and s_L  are variables ?

Comment: yes they are variables

Comment: what do you mean by `i` less than `2%`for which column 2% represents ? the same for 93% and 5.5 and 7.5

Comment: see under the description in the spec table it has max value of 2% so when the product 1001 comes in you look at its description i which must be less than 2% so thats why it will compare to the spec table i < spect table max i

Comment: It sounds like you need a new set of entries in your spec table, and then a way to indicate which set of specifications a product is supposed to adhere to. Trying to fudge your existing checks to bend the existing specification isn't a good idea as you'll just introduce gaps for other product checks to fall through.

Comment: thats what i thought i could just add the different values into the spec table, but im not allowed to. Thats why its abit confusing to me, so im not sure how to go about it, maybe i need a calculation?

Comment: But a calculation would affect all checks. If you can't change the table you're going to have to hard-code the checks for product 1002, and use your existing check for everything else. Which isn't exactly ideal. It isn't really clear what you're doing though, so can't give any detailed advice on how to include that.

Comment: i cant fix it because the next product might be in with in the same range then it wount get detected

Comment: Right, but you don't know which rules should apply to *any* product. You don't know if the next one should follow the same rules as 1001 or 1002. You either have to have a table-driven mechanism to decide - e.g. give each product a flag or category - or hard-code all exceptions, which doesn't scale and is likely to be impractical as you might not know about a new product in time to hard-code how it should be handled.